# Discord.py - Embed thumbnail param - How to get user avatars for a command

Tags: python-3.x, embed, discord.py

This is the sole line of code which doesn't work:

```
embed.set_thumbnail(user.avatar_url)
```

It says 2 args were given when I amended it, possibly due to some syntactic sugar or some stuff. However in this current state, in which I have seen videos where it is working just fine, it throws an error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "C:\Users\BenHa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 898, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File 
"C:\Users\BenHa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 550, in invoke        
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File 
"C:\Users\BenHa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 70, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e 

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
    HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Invalid Form Body In embed.thumbnail.url: Not a well formed URL.
```

Not sure what to do really.

Comment: Could you try to `print(user.avatar_url)` before this line?

Comment: oh don't worry I found a fix

Comment: in case anyone faces the same problem, I changed the line to
" embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url) "

Comment: so simply adding the "url=" to declare that as the url seemed to make it work so thats nice

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want to.

Answer (score 9):

FIX: All I had to do was add "url=" declaring the paramater inside the tuple as a url, which I assumed was given (me being silly).